# Unable to get installed Azure Pipelines Plugin into Jira Cloud version

Tags: azure-pipelines, jira-plugin

I tried to Get the "Azure Pipelines for Jira" from the Marketplace to get installed in our Jira Cloud instance but failed with the following error:
"We run into a little trouble
It might just be a hiccup. Try again in a bit"
Can you tell how should I get this fixed to continue with the installation?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TepWu.png)